# How to save elements of array into Core Data in order

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, core-data

I want to save elements of array into Core Data, I tried many different methods, but no one of them didn't save all elements but save one last element from array. I know that I am rewriting element in Core Data but I don't add new element. I wrote below some methods which I tried. Please show me this programmatically How can I make it?

```
let superArray = ["Steve", "Marina", "Tom", "Scarlett", "Michael", "David"]
@IBAction func saveData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let personEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject
    var index = 0
    while index < superArray.count {
        personEntity.setValue(superArray[index], forKey: "namePerson")
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)
        index++
    }
}
```

The second method.

```
    let superArray = ["Steve", "John", "Tom", "Scarlett", "Michael", "David"]
    @IBAction func saveData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let personEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject

        var stringForSave: String!
        for item in superArray {
            stringForSave = item
//            personEntity.setValue(item, forKey: "namePerson")
//            managedObjectContext.save(nil)
        }
        personEntity.setValue(stringForSave, forKey: "namePerson")
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)
    }
```

The third method

```
var superArray = ["Steve", "John", "Tom", "Scarlett", "Michael", "David"]

@IBAction func saveData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let personEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject

    for var index = 0; index < superArray.count; index++ {
        var data = superArray[index]

        personEntity.setValue(data, forKey: "namePerson")
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only creating one instance and updating it in your loop. Move this into your loop `let personEntity =`

Comment: @DanielGalasko Please show me this programmatically

Comment: @DanielGalasko Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func saveData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    for item in superArray {
    let personEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Person
        personEntity.namePerson = item
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)

    }
}
```